# Check Target Group Target Health Status via Ansible AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to find a method of checking a targets health status for a target group within an Application Load Balancer via ansible.

There is a module that returns elb_target_group_facts which do not give me the information I need. Ansible also has a module for elb_target which only allows you to manage a target rather than returning its current health check status.

Can anyone advise on a method of retrieving this using the ansible AWS libraries?

To be clear what I am looking for is the current health check status for an instance target associated with a target group for a particular Application Load Balancer.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to resolve this through ansible in the end as it does not currently expose health check status for the target group instances that I could find. Instead I used python and boto3 directly and called the method [describe_target_health](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_target_health) to get the health check status.

Answer (score 1):

I used awscli wait for that:

```
- name: "wait for target group- ({{ TARGET_GROUP_ARN | quote }}) attached to a LB to become healthy"
  # The awscli command It will poll every 15 seconds until a successful state has been reached.
  # This will exit with a return code of 255 after 40 failed checks.
  command: >-
      aws --region {{ AWS_REGION }} elbv2 wait
      target-in-service --target-group-arn {{ TARGET_GROUP_ARN | quote }}
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  tags: liveness
```